# How can I make these info cards equal height?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation-5

I would like to use this block for my project, found on the foundation university. I am currently using the Foundation 5 version and I would like to set these columns equal height. Fix height px is not a solution because it will have a large empty bottom area on small screen devices. Here is the full code:

http://zurb.com/building-blocks/info-card-with-corner-lables

Answer (score 2):

Add the following CSS to your example:

```
.row {
    align-items:stretch;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.columns {
    align-self:stretch;
    display:flex; 
}
```

Additional you have to add `align-self:stretch;` to the class `.callout-card`. Here you can find a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v1fcxp0t/